# useContext with tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using the `useContext` hook and `tsx`.

```
const StoreContext = createContext({});

export function useStore() {
   const [store] = useContext(StoreContext);
   return store;
}

export function useDispatch() {
    const [, dispatch] = useContext(StoreContext);
    return dispatch;
}
```

I am getting the same error for both `[store]` and `[dispatch]`.

> Type '{}' is not an array type

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: change `const StoreContext = createContext({});` to `const StoreContext = createContext([]);` let me know if it helps

Comment: nice,  I think that could be it. Just building here, will let you know

Comment: not really, led to more errors :-D beauty of typescript

Comment: hmm ok. I think the error is not because of the code you share can you provide more related code.

Answer (score 3):

Tell TypeScript what is the type of your context by providing a type parameter for `createContext`.

Consider this example:

```
interface Theme {
  mode: 'light' | 'dark'
}
```

`Thame` is the shape of our context. This interface needs to go to `createContext`:

```
const StoreContext = React.createContext<Theme>({ mode: 'dark' });

const { mode } = React.useContext(StoreContext);

(mode === 'dark') || (mode === 'light') // true
```

Your context doesn't have to be an object. In this example, context is made of an array of numbers.

```
const StoreContext = React.createContext<number[]>([0]);

const [first, ...rest] = React.useContext(StoreContext);

(typeof first === 'number') // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use useContext, and it didn't work. I saw recommendation to downgrade React and ReactDOM to 16.7.0-alpha-2, but that didn't work either. The solution for my problem was to wrap the component in myContext.Consumer. For class-based component, you can use yourClass.contextType = yourContext, and then you can acess features using "this.context". Please refer to this documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html